# How to get easy tether to install on samsung chromebook 2 in ubuntu which was installed using crouton?

Tags: 32-bit

When trying to install easytether, I get a wrong architecture 'i386' message. Is there a way to get this to install?

Answer (score 0):

If it's accusing a wrong architecture, it probably means you're running a 64-bit processor ( "i386" represents 32-bit processors). Try downloading the amd64 version of EasyTether at http://www.mobile-stream.com/easytether/drivers.html.

Comment: It is 32 bit. The Samsung 13" chromebook 2 is ARM architecture, which I don't think easytether will install on. Unless there is a work around?